# Llamada Ajax se repite infinitamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

buenas tardes a todos! Luego de quemarme la cabeza un buen rato y buscar por todos lados sin poder resolver nada, vengo a comentar mi problema, a ver si a alguien le ha sucedido lo mismo.

Tengo una vista que en el "$('document').ready()" tiene una llamada a la función "fillZoneTable". La funcion es:

```
function fillZoneTable(){
$.ajax({
    url: '/admin-menu/zones/get-zones',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{
        orderBy: $('#orderBy').val(),
        order: $('#order').val(),
        'param': $('#filterSearch').val()
    },
    success: function(res){         
        if(res['type'] == 'response'){
            zones = res['zones'];
            goToPage(0)
        }
    },

    error: function(er){
        $('#messageModalTitle').html('Error');
        $('#messageModalMessage').html('Ha ocurrido un error inesperado');
        $('#messageModal').modal('show');
    }
});}
```

Esa funcion pide a un metodo PHP un array con datos, el cual trae sin problemas, y puedo manipularlo correctamente desde el "success". En dicho success guardo los datos en una variable global (Se que esto es un asco, pero por ahora lo estoy haciendo así), y luego llamo a la función "goToPage()" que luego usaré para paginar.

El problema es que, sin importar que tenga la función "goToPage", siempre, siempre, siempre, SIEMPRE, vuelve a ejecutar la función "fillZoneTable()". De manera que se me vuelve un bucle infinito de ejecuciones de Ajax...

Para que se den una idea, la función "goToPage" lo unico que tiene ahora es una sola linea: "alert('test')", y sin embargo al llamarla, ejecuta "fillZoneTable()".

Quite la función del document ready y la llamé desde consola, y luego, desde la misma consola, llemé a "goToPage()", sin embrago ni siquiera entra en la función, sino que ejecuta "fillZoneTable()".

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea? No puedo seguir perdiendo tiempo con esto!!!!!

Comment: ¿E qué lugar de tu código estás llamando a `fillZoneTable`? Específicamente el código relativo a: _Tengo una vista que en el "$('document').ready()" tiene una llamada a la función "fillZoneTable"_

Comment: La vista es un blade.php que tiene esto debajo de todo:

<script>
  $('document').ready(function(){
   fillZoneTable();
  });
</script>

Comment: Sitúa un resumen del código de tu vista con la llamada a la función. Siempre intenta dar todo el contexto del problema que presentas, es muy común que sitúes un código pensando que el problema está ahí, cuando en realidad el problema está en otra parte de tu código, mientras más contexto des, más fácil será encontrar el problema.

Comment: Emmm, coloque todo y fuí super especifico. ¿Queres la vista? ¿Para que? Es solo un html que no tiene nada de nada, y al final de todas las tags tiene lo que mencioné...

Comment: Además el error lo temriné resolviendo... Renombre la función goToPage(), osea le cambie el nombre, y funciona todo perfecto. La verdad no tengo ni la menor idea de porque